# Reference for construction of coproduct of Boolean algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, category-theory, boolean-algebra, limits-colimits

I was recently trying to understand how coproducts of Boolean algebras work, since I need them for my research. I came across a StackExchange [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143783/coproducts-and-pushouts-of-boolean-algebras-and-heyting-algebras) with a great constructive answer from "Math Student 020".

However, even after a lot of searching, I can't seem to find a reference to use for such a construction. I don't have access to the one "Math Student 020" mentioned (from P.T. Johnstone). Does anybody know a reference I could use for a **constructive** characterization of the coproduct of Boolean algebras? Thanks!

Comment: Oups after writing my answer, I realized that maybe your question is just a reference request, not a request for a construction?

Comment: Yes, it is primarily a reference request. But your alternative construction was also quite helpful to read. If you have a reference for that one it could help me as well.

Comment: I see. Then the tag "reference request" is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I added the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The category of Boolean algebras is isomorphic to the category of Boolean rings, so let's work with these.

Every Boolean is a commutative $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra.

When $R$ is a commutative ring, the category of commutative $R$-algebras has a coproduct. It is the tensor product $A \otimes_R B$ equipped with the multiplication

$$(A \otimes_R B) \otimes_R (A \otimes_R B) \xrightarrow{\cong} (A \otimes_R A) \otimes_R (B \otimes_R B) \xrightarrow{\mu_A \otimes \mu_B} A \otimes_R B$$
and the unit $1_A \otimes 1_B$.

If $A,B$ are Boolean rings, then the tensor product $A \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} B$ is again a Boolean ring: In fact, since it is a commutative $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra, the Frobenius $r \mapsto r^2$ is *additive*, so it suffices to check $r^2=r$ on elementary tensors $r = a \otimes b$, where it is clear.

It follows formally that $A \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_2} B$ is also the coproduct of $A$ and $B$ in the category of Boolean rings.

Notice that there cannot be a very easy description. In fact, the coproduct of Boolean rings corresponds to the product of Stone spaces (via Stone duality), which is of course easy to describe, but the Boolean algebra of compact-open subsets in a product of Stone spaces is *not* easy to describe (but of course it exists).

Comment: Thank you for the fast and illuminating response! Do you by any chance have a reference for this to some paper/book?

Comment: I would also have to dig into some books, but it's indeed quite basic. I have just simplified the construction (we don't need the reflector).